# Add items to ul and delete them

Tags: jquery, addition

I want to add some list items to and unorderdlist  with a click on a button.
And I want to delete those items when I click on a button.

This is what I have made.. I can add them but not delete them. Can you help me?

```
<div class="mydive">
<button id="add">click</button>
<div data-titel="Dit is de titel" data-price="55 euro"></div>
</div>
<ul>

</ul>

$('#add').click(function() {
    var activiteit = $(this).next('div').data();
    var title = activiteit.titel;
    var price = activiteit.price;
    $('ul').append("<li>" + title + price + "</li>" + "<button class='delete'>delete</button>");
});
$('.delete').click(function() {
    $(this).prev('li').remove();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezmmzqmL/)

Comment: change your line `$('.delete').click(function() {`  to `$(document).on("click",".delete",function() { `. this should work.... https://jsfiddle.net/ezmmzqmL/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use event delegation :

```
$(document.body).on('click','.delete',function() {
    $(this).prev('li').remove();
});
```

`-->`  https://jsfiddle.net/ezmmzqmL/

btw, don't put `button` directly under `UL`, put it inside `LI` instead

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event delegation here.

```
$('ul').on("click",".delete",function() {
    $(this).prev('li').remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ezmmzqmL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
jQuery(document.body).on("click",".delete",function() {
    jQuery(this).prev('li').remove();
    jQuery(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/ezmmzqmL/4/)

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    var activiteit = $(this).next('div').data();
    var title = activiteit.titel;
    var price = activiteit.price;
    $('ul').append("<li>" + title + price + "</li>" + "<button class='delete'>delete</button>");
});
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {    
    $(this).prev('li').remove();
    $(this).remove();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a 'delete' button. Then what? You just append it to the DOM. You don't attach any click handler to it after creating it. Classic dynamic element problem.

Why your code doesn't work :

```
$('#add').click(function() { // <-- This is executed first.
    ...
    // This is executed THIRD, whenever you click '#add'
    $('ul').append("<li>" + title + price + "</li>" + "<button class='delete'>delete</button>");
});

$('.delete').click(function() { // <-- This is executed SECOND, but no delete button exists yet.
    $(this).prev('li').remove();
});
```

As said in the four other answers, use event delegation...

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes to ypur code and you can see the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezmmzqmL/6/)
here.
I have wrapped each of your li item in a `span` so that i could target it using javascript `previousSibling()` property and empty it's `innerHTML`(which is also a javascript property) removing every content inside the span i.e The delete button and the `li` element itself.

```
<div class="mydive">
    <button id="add">click</button>
    <div data-titel="Dit is de titel" data-price="55 euro"></div>
</div>
<ul>

</ul>
```

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    var activiteit = $(this).next('div').data();
    var title = activiteit.titel;
    var price = activiteit.price;
    $('ul').append("<span id='asd'><li>" + title + price + "</li>" + "<button class='delete' onclick='this.parentNode.innerHTML=\"\"'>delete</button></span>");
});
```